# back button in fragments android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, button

I was creating a simple application with android studio, and when I create a fragment it inserts me by default in the top left a little button to go back, how can I make it active or delete it?

Thanks for the attention

[image: back darth]

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your onCreate, it will remove the back button:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

For details: https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/up-action